# Is there any way to send Email Reminder before one day of charging subscription installment in stripe

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Is there any way to send Email Reminder before one day of charging subscription installment in stripe

```
$stripe_subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create([
  'customer' => $stripe_customer->id,
  'payment_behavior' => 'allow_incomplete',
  'items' => [
      [
          'price' => $price->id,
      ],
  ],
  'metadata' => ['Address' => "address"],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the [Dashboard settings](https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/billing/automatic) page to configure an email reminder. However, the minimum is 3 days before the subscription renewals.